# Documents in Cloud Firestore is not showing up in query result in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

[image: Detail Cloud firestore structure][image: Screenshot of Cloud Firestore]

[image: Code to retrieve document from Cloud Firestore]

[image: More Detail]

```
  void onSendMessage(String content) {
    
    if (content.trim() != '') {
      textEditingController.clear();
      var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(widget.comid)
          .collection(widget.comid)
          .doc(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        transaction.set(
          documentReference,
          {
            'idFrom': widget.userid,
            'idTo': widget.peerid,
            'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
            'content': content,
            
          },
        );
      });
    }
    else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: 'Nothing to send', 
        backgroundColor: Colors.black, 
        textColor: Colors.grey[100]
      );
    }
  }
```

I want to get those document id but its not coming in query. However, when I add "Anakans" manually through firestore it shows up.

I am new to flutter and firestore where I am doing the mistake

**Solved**
I set the document field with most value of most recent message. Thus the document no longer a non-existent ancestor. And I can fetch the list of ids. Now my `onSendMessage` function looks like

```
  void onSendMessage(String content) {
    if (content.trim() != '') {
      textEditingController.clear();

      var msg = {
        'idFrom': widget.userid,
        'idTo': widget.peerid,
        'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
        'content': content,
      };

      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(widget.comid)
          .set(msg);

      var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(widget.comid)
          .collection(widget.comid)
          .doc(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        transaction.set(
          documentReference,
          {
            'idFrom': widget.userid,
            'idTo': widget.peerid,
            'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
            'content': content,
          },
        );
      });
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Nothing to send',
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          textColor: Colors.grey[100]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is `onSendMessage` used to add the messages that you want to get in your query? Then post your actual code (not screenshots of the code)

Comment: Please provide more information would be happy to help) and why transaction not just set?

Comment: @PeterO. ```onSendMessage``` adds the message between users it is creating this documentreference 
```      var documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .doc(widget.comid)
          .collection(widget.comid)
          .doc(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());
```
And then I am adding it using transaction

Comment: I am curious what is .doc(widget.comid).collection(widget.comid) here?

Comment: I got the problem but i cant figure out the solution. So when i am calling ```onSendMessage``` it is creating document as **Non-existent ancestor documents in cloud firestore** . Thats why i cant get it while query. What is the other way around to implement ```onSendMessage```, so that it dont become **Non-existent ancestor documents **

Comment: Check my answer, you can use that.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code. I have seen the issue.

`onSendMessage` adds a document to this path `messages/widget.comid/widget.comid/DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()`

`onSendMessage` did not add any document to `messages` collection, so messages collection is actually empty. Rather, it added a document to this path `messages/widget.comid/widget.comid/DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()`. So `messages/widget.comid` does not exist because you didn't add any document to `messages`.

In firestore, a child document can exist even if the parent does not exist.

So '4ePoQ...' as a document, does not exist but it has a child (because you defined the path). Documents that do not exist are in italics (as you can see from your firestore screenshot). When you add `ankana` manually, you are adding a document to the messages collection.

Solution. Your stream builder should listen to the subcollection `widget.comid`. This collection has documents (with id `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString()`).

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Title'),
  ),
  body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('messages')
        .doc(widget.comid)
        .collection(widget.comid)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Something went wrong');
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();

      if (snapshot.data.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        print('document exists');
        print(snapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e.data()));
        return Container();
      } else {
        print(snapshot.data.docs);
        print('document does not exist');
        return Container();
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for going through the trouble, very much appreciate it. My app design doesnt have widget.comid present when i want that document id. Actually that widget.comid is the document id. I want list of all the document id at one go and show it to a screen. So, I need a way to avoid putting document path and create document_id  and then create collection so that i can access the list later.

Comment: Okay, to do that, let `onSendMessage` add documents to `messages/doc_id`. then you fetch it the way you are presently doing. I don't think you need timestamp as doc_id since you are not fetching with it.